# Material UI Autocomplete: change margin between inputRoot and input

Tags: css, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, margin

In a project of mine I've been using Material-UI's Autocomplete. Even though this component is not very resizing friendly I've successfully been able to alter some of the width's/height's and font sizes. However I'm now stuck with dealing with a huge margin between the inputRoot and input when I resize my viewport as you can see in the following images. I already searched through the Documentation and wasn't able to find which atribute can I change in order to be able to size this margin with vw units which will allow it to resize the way that I want.  Some images to illustrate my problem. As you can see when I shrink the viewport the red and green space shrinks as well but since the margin ( represented with a pink line ) stays constant it looks relatively much bigger. I want it to shrink as well. :

[image]
[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import { makeStyles , withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    input: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "1.4vw",
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        fontSize: "1.25vw",
        color: "#02112E",
        backgroundColor: "red",
    },
    option: {
      fontSize: "0.8vw",
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      height: "3vw",
      width: "100%",
      color: "#02112E",
    },
    noOption: {
      fontSize: "0.8vw",
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      height: "1.2vw",
      width: "100%",
      color: "#02112E"
    },
    root: {
      '& label.Mui-focused': {
        color: '#00ff00',
        fontSize: "0.97vw",
        height: "1vw",
      },
      '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
        borderBottomColor: '#02112E',
        borderBottomWidth: "0.21vw"
      },
      '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
        borderBottomColor: '#02112E',
        borderBottomWidth: "0.07vw"
      },
      '& .MuiInput-underline:hover::before': {
        borderBottomColor: '#02112E',
        borderBottomWidth: "0.07vw"
      },
      fontSize: "1.25vw",
      width: "100%",
    },
    inputRoot: {
      color: "#02112E",
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      fontSize: "1.25vw",
      backgroundColor: "green",
    }
  });

  
  
  export default function CountrySelect() {
    const classes = useStyles();
  
    return (
      <Autocomplete
        style={{ width: "60%", height: "3.47vw" }}
        options={list}
        classes={{
          root: classes.root,
          option: classes.option,
          noOptions: classes.noOption,
          input: classes.input
        }}
        disableClearable
        freeSolo
        noOptionsText={'Sem Opções'}
        autoHighlight
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        renderOption={(option) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            {option.title}
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Option"
            variant="standard"
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              autoComplete: 'new-password', // disable autocomplete and autofill
            }}
            InputLabelProps={{
              classes: {
                root: classes.inputRoot
              }
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  }

  
const list = [
  { title: 'opt 1'},
  { title: 'opt 2'},
];
```

DEMO:

https://2y3jh.csb.app/

Comment: Here is your demo: https://94xlp.csb.app/ I would say not to use viewport width for height because when you shrink the browser, the ratio differs. But you can also combine with media queries to use an appropriate viewport width.

Comment: This does not solve my problem... I want to change the margin between inputRoot and input and I am not seeing any resolution for that on the code you sent me.

Comment: No, I mean you need to show your demo to people here. Not just the code, how can someone debug without seeing your demo. That is why I added it here.

Comment: https://2y3jh.csb.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to your `root`

```
"& label + .MuiInput-formControl":{
  marginTop:"1vw"
},
```

Also you might want to add this to your `inputRoot` so it doesn't fall below the drop down on smaller screens

```
transform: "translate(0, 2vw) scale(1)"
```